# JRebel Uninstallation issue

Tags: jrebel

I have installed trial version of **JRebel** for evaluation. Its a good tool no doubt. But my company doesn't want invest on **JRebel**. I am trying to uninstall from my eclipse.

It says that its uninstalled. But still I see **JRebel** things in my eclipse. Any help on how to do clean uninstall of **JRebel** will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look under
_Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> JRebel -> Uninstall_

Comment: I did. But the issue remains. It says that its going to uninstall and it will prompt me for restart. But after restart I still see Jrebel things.

Comment: Perhap [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614308/jrebel-config-center-not-displayed-failed-to-create-parts-controls/26626499#26626499) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just reinstalled and uninstalled using Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> JRebel -> Uninstall. It worked. Thanks @V-k